# Vertical centre positioning trouble in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I'm having some cascading style issues [here](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/o-mne) - when height of screen is smaller than 680px it works fine (position is added absolutely, because my client is against responsiveness of his website), but when it's big position of `<div class="container">` tag should be relative / vertically in center of page.

That works in FF, Chrome, IE but not in Safari and I don't know how to fix it (and I've spent so much time with that trouble), thanks for your advice and help.

Structure is following:

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="container> 
     TEXT
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS setted to the elements are:

```
.content {
   min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 316px);
   min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 316px);
   min-height: calc(100vh - 316px);
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
.content > .container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: : translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: : translate(-50%, -50%);
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was working, but jquery.js.map file was missing and that has caused the troubles.